# python string split only by `/` but not `//`

Tags: python, string, split

For example, I have a string as:

`str = 's3://files.production/object/Image/110/image.jpg'`

and I would like to split it into:

`'s3://files.production'` and `'object/Image/110/image.jpg'`.

I am wondering if there is any convenient way to do it.

Comment: Assuming what you're using to split accepts regex

Comment: `re.split('(?<!/)/(?!/)', 's3://files.production/object/Image/110/image.jpg', 1)`

Comment: someone closed this question i couldn't submit my answer, anyway the convenient way to do this is by using urllib.parse, check : https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#url-parsing